# Get file from AWS S3 using apex

Tags: apex, callout, amazon-s3

we are uploading files to AWS (S3 protocol) on CASE object. it's a simple call out and file gets uploaded successfully. We are storing the uploaded URL into a different custom object to display them on parent record's related list as if like actual attachment links. But I am not able to fetch the File which is supposedly happen when user clicks on that link. I have been getting below error...

**System.HttpResponse[Status=Forbidden, StatusCode=403]**

***SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method***

Here is the code snippet..Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public FileDownLoad()
{ 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
    req.setHeader('Authorization',createAuthHeader(method,filename ,formattedDateString ,bucketname ,key,secret));
    Set<String> getParams = new Set<String> {
    'prefix=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(filename+'/','UTF-8'),
    'delimiter=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/', 'UTF-8')
    };

    String endpointBase = 'https://' + bucketname + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + filename1;

    req.setEndpoint(endpointBase + '?' + 'prefix=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(filename+'/','UTF-8')+'&delimiter=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/', 'UTF-8'));

    String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' +
        attach.ContentType + '\n' +
        formattedDateString + '\n' +
        '/' + bucketname + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename;

    Http http = new Http();

    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}
public string createAuthHeader(String method,String filename,String formattedDateString,String bucket,String key,String secret){
       string auth;
       String stringToSign = method+'\n\n\n'+formattedDateString+'\n/'+bucket +'/'+filename;
       Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', blob.valueof(stringToSign),blob.valueof(secret));
       String sig = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
       auth = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + sig;
       return auth;

   }
```

Comment: Can you try setting your endpoint as: `req.setEndpoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + bucketname + '/' + filename);`

Comment: Tried., Same error.

Answer (score 5):

```
public FileDownLoad()
...
String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' +
...
```

This doesn't make sense if you are trying to *download* a file.  Download is `GET`... not `PUT`.

Comment: Changed it to GET but still the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This fixed the issues. Looks like, number of '\'es caused the problem (PUT method has 3 and GET had 2).

String stringtosign = 'GET\n\n\n'+Lexpires+'\n/'+bucketname+'/'+filename;